# document.getElementsByTagName() returns length of zero (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, dom

Any ideas why one would get weird results out of `document.getElementsByTagName()` ?

[image: asp.net example]

I've experimented with [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbytagname_length) `document.getElementsByTagName()` example and the same javascript code works just fine. However `console.log(x)` returns slightly different looking log.

Just one other variable. I am using `asp:Repeater` to spit out that table which in turn builds [Open in OneDrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) links using `asp:HyperLink`. If it makes any difference.!?

[image: w3schools example]

**Just so you don't have to type the javascript yourself:**

```
// replace text with icon
function below720(mq) {
    var tags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    console.log('tag', tags);
    console.log('tag.length', tags.length);
    for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) { 
        if (tags[i].innerHTML == "Open in OneDrive") {
            tags[i].innerHTML = "<img src='Images/file.gif' alt='url icon' />";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could show us the HTML output for the <a> tags?

Comment: My bet: you are calling your method before the anchors are added to the page. When is your method called?

Comment: @epascarello might just have it. Let wrap javascript in ``document.ready()``.

Comment: And that was literally it. Don't know how I didn't think of that, duh...

Answer (score 0):

+1 goes to @epascarello for point out my silly mistake of trying to execute javascript code before anchors had a chance to initialise.